# How do I create a realistic magnetic force field?

Tags: animation, force-fields

I'm looking to make a realistic simple magnetic force field. Similar to the one in this video at strength -2, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEdIROlQu_s
When I actually try to use the magnetic force field option, it just has the particles flaring out one way. I'm trying to use this to show neuron fields which look extremely similar to both solar and magnetic fields. Help!

Comment: Please try adding more detail to your question. We can't help without knowing more about your setup

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information to your question. Show images of your current settings.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for commenting! I actually was able to create it after posting this question, just not sure how to close it! I just put up another if you could help me on that one it would be great!

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question, please post  the answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to make the outcome look as realistic as possible. The problem I was running into was adding the force field to the plane rather than adding one via SHIFT+A. From there I was able to edit it in the physics to get a strength of -2. I changed the seed to 1, for my own model and it looks similar to the real thing. Mine is also different since I made my particles based off of a teal sphere unlike the lines as seen in the video. I think it adds to showing the pathway of the particles better. You can play with the particle settings however you like for your model, and just kept changing my numbers around to find what fit best for me! If you have any other further questions let me know!